# Exporting HTML icons as PDF

Tags: html, pdf, icons, font-awesome

I have a webpage with material-icon and font-awesome icons. However, when I try to export the HTML website as PDF (using web tools, plugins or Adobe Acrobat DC for Mac), the icons are not shown (it just shows a the name of the icon).

I am including the css references to both sets of icons like this in my index.html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

If then I try to use a material.io icon in my index.html as follows:

```
<i class="material-icons">translate</i>
```

the result is:

- The icon is shown in the browser (good).
- Some tools to export HTML as PDF can handle it (however, they do not allow me to select texts, so my PDF is a bit poor).
- Other tools cannot process those icons (as
  Adobe Acrobat DC, which allows text selection in exported PDFs). In
  the example above, it just shows the text "translate" instead of the
  icon associated to "translate".

Is there any way I can change my index.html, or CSS file or exportation tools to make the icons are shown when exporting to PDF? By the way, the same happens with font-awesome, not only with material-icons.

Thanks a lot and kind regards.

Comment: Are you using any media queries?

Comment: @freginold I am. However, I've deleted all the media queries from my CSS in order to see if there is any change in result, but the behaviour remains the same without media queries.

Comment: Do you have any SVG or canvas elements in your HTML?  Do they render correctly when converted to PDF?

Comment: Font awesome icons use :before which is not in the HTML Dom and some tools do not process them. See http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.GlyphIcons

Comment: @freginold I am not using SVG or canvas elements, so I don't know. Kevin Brown I will try GlyphIcons then. I would prefer to correct something in my project instead of changing the icon source, but if it is the only way to make it work, I will try it, of course. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinBrown I have tried the Glyphicons, but I it still gives me problems Even more, the fonts are completely changed when I import the Glyphicons using this:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium / phantomJS to take the screenshot of the HTML page and create pdf of same.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver.get(url);
```

Comment: Does that work if the page is longer than the screen height (i.e. if there's a scroll bar, does it capture the entire page)?

Comment: @yogeeshr thanks for the info. However, I don't know how to begin implement this tool in my project (but I can search). Thanks.

Comment: By the way @yogeeshr, I can take a pic/pdf of a webpage using e.g. a Chrome extension called FireShot. However, exported texts are not selectable, and that is a big problem in my case... I would need a pdf exportation tool that would allow text to be selectable and icons to be shown. Thanks anyway.